# Recalculating duration on EOF in libvlc

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I have a really specific use-case where in prod I have to play back a continously appended wav file in my java application (I have no way of modify this scenario).

My problem is that when I open this wav file for playback libvlc handles the duration calculation, and after a while it detects EOF, despite the file actual length is much larger since we opened it (my guess is because of buffered playback). This causes the player to stop (raise the `finished` event). As of today I restart the playback and set the time to the end position from this finished event. This causes little pauses and unacceptable in the final product.

I try to implement a logic in libvlc (vlc 3.0.6 version) that will handle this problem, but I can't really find out the proper way of doing it.

My approach would be to recalculate the duration of the wav file in case it's detecting EOF. If the new duration equals the old one than it is really EOF else it can continue playback.

I have tied to modify the `VLC_DEMUXER_EOF` handling in `input.c`, follow the file end trace, modify the `demux-run.c` and `wav.c` process, and to play around with the event handling (`finished`/`stopped`), but cannot get much closer to a valid solution.

I would really appreciate some help with this one, because I loosing my hair rapidly in the last couple of days. (I'm open for alternatives too, if you have some idea.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which binding you are using, but I'm assuming vlcj since you mentioned Java.

Anyway, one solution could be to use `libvlc_media_new_callbacks`. Doc: https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media.html#ga591c3cbe56444f1949165b2b9b75d8e2

Implementing these custom callbacks will allow you to tell libvlc explicitly to *wait*. You can do this in the `libvlc_media_read_cb` callback, where the documentation states:

> If no data is immediately available, then the callback should sleep.

You should find how this API is exposed through whichever binding you use and then use it from Java code.

Comment: Tank you for your answer. Yes, I'm using vlcj. I did not know about this callback overriding, so it helps in the long run. The problem with this approach seems that I still not able to tell vlcj to recalculate the duration of the input file. Or at least there is no way I'm aware of.

Comment: you manage the reading of the input file or stream in the read playback. If you need to wait for me data, then you make the callback thread sleep until you have more data. Duration doesn't matter, it can be a never ending stream

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it in the near future, because it's much cleaner than my present solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to modify the wav file handling in the libvlc source, and build a new vlc player for this specific problem.

By updating the `i_data_size` in the wav.c `Control` method, with the `stearm_Size(p_demux->s)` the player was able to manage the appending, and plays back the files like they were streams (this possibly generates issues with the lenght_change event).

And secondly I have to manage occasional collision, when the appender allocates the file, and stream block operations cannot be executed. I managed this problem by implementing a retry mechanism to the stream.c `vlc_stream_ReadRaw` method. This will retry the `s->pf_read(s, buf, len)` call x times with some microsleep, if it returns 0 (it means EOF in usual playbacks, but here it can indicate failed operation).

This is NOT a proper solution by any means, but I was in a hurry, and had to make it work. I will accept the solution described by [mfkl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907672/recalculating-duration-on-eof-in-libvlc/64923575#64923575).